# Scratch org Experiences/Communities features missing about 25% of the time

Tags: community, salesforcedx, jenkins, ci

We have a Jenkins build that creates scratch orgs using this project-scratch-def.json:

```
{
    "orgName": "Xyz",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "features": ["Communities", "Sites"],
    "settings": {
        "apexSettings": {
            "enableCompileOnDeploy": true
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
            "enableOotbProfExtUserOpsEnable": true
        }
    }
}
```

and seemingly randomly but quite often the code push into the created scratch org fails with:

```
where Id in (select ParentId from NetworkMemberGroup where NetworkId

ERROR at Row:4:Column:51
sObject type 'NetworkMemberGroup' is not supported. If you are attempting to use
a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please
reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (1222:41)
```

where `NetworkMemberGroup` is an SObject type related to Experiences/Communities.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**PS**

Related to akarnid's comment, anyone know the easiest way with sfdx of reading back from the org to check a setting such as `enableNetworksEnabled`?

Comment: Seen this problem lots of times in the years I've used SFDX. Sometimes it just fails to activate a platform feature for the scratch org for no good or visible reason and then you see that error.  Only way I've eve known to fix it just to run the same command again and (usually) then it works.
Sorry I don't have any concrete answers or a solution to this.

Comment: Thanks @akarnid. Perhaps I will have to resort to retrying: something like reading back the setting when the org create has completed so that the retry happens in the first few minutes (of a 45 minute build as several products are installed). Not sure that sfdx helps do that too directly; could just run the potentially failing query.

Comment: Is it worth trying to query `Status` of [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_network.htm)?

Comment: Hi @JefersonChaves, Yeah though I suspect that object isn't there until communities enabled so the check would be error/no error. Was hoping for a cool sfdx one liner...

Comment: I see, the other alternative might be to check [orgPreferenceSettings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm) for `NetworksEnabled`. This might be more in line with your question at the end.

Comment: Have seen this multiple times including one for turning on Account Contact Relationship, one approach that have helped us is scratch org pools, where such failed scratch orgs get.eliminated. If you are interested, here is links.to article to get.you started. Scratch orgs @ Scale Part 2
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/scratch-orgs-scale-part-2-caitlyn-mills